# Bash: accessing a large array at random indices is slow

Tags: arrays, bash, performance

When I create a large bash array (i.e. >10000 elements), accessing it at random positions is slow.

Consider the following example:

```
a=($(seq 1000000))
while true; do
    idx=$(( ($RANDOM * 32786 + $RANDOM) % 1000000 ))
    echo ${a[idx]}
done | pv -r --line-mode 1>/dev/null
```

This shows me a throughput of a measly 500 lines per second.
Eluding the access brings the performance back up to reasonable levels.

Why is this? Are arrays somehow implemented in a weird fashion?

In a more realistic example, I'm reading some 1Mio IDs from a file and trying to prepare around 100k buckets (i.e. output lines) with 30 IDs each, concatenated by `:`. Is there a way I could do that quickly?

Comment: Do not use interpreter language. if you need performance use C, Perl, Python ...

Comment: Could you give a more realistic samples of your file with IDs and expected output (a few lines)? Using `awk` or `perl` could be faster here

Comment: The main performance issue you're having is the fact that the full array is in memory. It would be much faster to process IDs from the file as they come while reading the file. Please provide a input sample and expected output to get a clue.

Comment: The IDs are just a non-coninuous set of numbers. If you want a more realistic example: `a=($(for i in {1..1000000}; do echo $(( $RANDOM * 32786 + $RANDOM )); done))` should do just fine.

Comment: @Cyrus I realize that bash performance isn't great. But what really made me make this issue is that accessing an array is ~100 times more expensive than e.g. invoking `echo`. And I'm curious why.

Comment: Take a look at the array implementation in the source code (array.c), quote: "*Arrays are sparse doubly-linked lists. An element's index is stored with it.*". So this differs from C which just uses pointer arithmetic in contiguous memory, or languages that use a hash. Bash has to search sequentially through the list looking for the index it needs, it was never designed for the kind of problem you are giving it, indeed early shells had a limit of 4096 entries in an array.  It is the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @cdarke: You can make that an answer…

Comment: If you prepare 100k buckets of 30 IDs, you will need more than a million IDs so there will be repetition, surely?

Comment: Yes, but I don't particularly care about how those repetitions are distributed. (i.e. whether after picking an ID the chance for picking it again remains the same as picking all others - I only know the correct terms in German, I'm fine with either "Ziehen mit/ohne zurücklegen".)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite bash being indeed the wrong tool for the job (linked lists… see comments above), it is still possible to do this with acceptable performance, using a coproc and `shuf -r`.

An a bit elaborate example, requires `$a` from above:

```
(
     shopt -s lastpipe
     coproc rid { 
         for e in "${a[@]}"; do
             echo "$e"; 
         done | shuf -r; 
     };
     seq 150000 \
     | while read s; do
         for i in {1..10}; do
             read -u ${rid[0]} a;
             s="$s:$a";
         done;
         echo "$s";
     done
) | pv -ls 150000 >/dev/null
```

- The `-r` gets `shuf` to not shuffle, but just spit out random elements without remembering indefinitely.
- The outer `( )` is necessary because I wanted the output of the loop to go to `pv` for measuring. This shows a problem I have with this solution: I don't think coprocs are easy to use, since you cannot read their output from a subshell and you have to think about how to terminate them cleanly. `shopt -s lastpipe` may help with some problems.

All in all, this is about a factor 200 faster than the original version (take this with more than one grain of salt), but of course still a similar factor slower than an optimized native implementation.